# Looking for assistance writing a function for JS to complete a task

Tags: javascript

I need Write a function that makes the following calculation:

```
param1 + param2 - param3 + param4 – param5…
```

and keeps with this pattern. If
any non-numerical character is encountered, ¼ of its value is computed as the
numerical value. The result should truncate precision.

E.G.

```
function(11,’a’,2,30,’z’,3) returns 35
```

*11 + (97/4) - 2 + 30 - (122/4) + 3*

I **CAN'T** use `String` built-in functions:

```
endsWith()
includes() 
indexOf()
lastIndexOf()
localeCompare()
match()
repeat()
replace()
search()
slice()
split()
startsWith()
substr()
substring()
toLocaleLowerCase()
toLocaleUpperCase()
toLowerCase()
toString()
toUpperCase()
trim()
trimLeft()
trimRight()
valueOf()
```

Also I **CAN'T** use `Array` built-in functions

```
concat()
copyWithin()
every()
fill()
filter()
find()
findIndex()
forEach()
indexOf()
isArray()
join()
lastIndexOf()
map()
pop()
push()
reduce()
reduceRight()
reverse()
shift()
slice()
some()
sort()
splice()
toString()
unshift()
valueOf()
```

Comment: right. what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide more info on what you are trying to achieve, efforts you made and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shot:

```js
const d = (...a) => {
  let total = a[0];
  
  for (let i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    total += (+a[i] == a[i] ? a[i] : Math.round(a[i].charCodeAt(0) / 4)) * (i & 1 ? 1 : -1);  
  }
  
  return total;
};

console.log(d(11, 'a', 2, 30, 'z', 3));
```

Explanation: accumulate a total starting with the first argument. If the current element isn't an integer, turn it into one and divide by 4 with rounded (not truncated) result. Finally, multiply by 1 or -1 depending on the parity of the index to alternate addition and subtraction.

PS: It's a good idea to try these problems first yourself instead of letting us have all the fun!